# how to decode XML request response from download URL using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, python-requests

I'm using `requests` library to get XML data from a specific URL and parse it to a `pandas` dataframe. When I copy and paste it to my browser it automatically downloads the XML file. But when I use the requests library it returns a very large string of bytes or something.
The code is as follows:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import warnings

#don't want to print warnings now
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

#state url
url = "https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/downloadDocumento?id=137574"

#make request
r = requests.get(url,verify=False)

print(r.text)
```

The print result is

```
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
```

What I am doing wrong? Is there some way to decode this response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payload is Base64 encoded. Decode it with `base64.b64decode`

```py
import base64
base64.b64decode(r.text)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64